# Cypher: Finding a node based on its number of distinct relationship types

Tags: graph, neo4j, cypher

Using Cypher, how can I find nodes that have **x or more   relationships of distinct types**, and are **connected to y or more different nodes**?

For instance, a:Person can be connected to b:Person, via relationships of type 'family','friend','coworker'.

How do we find a, such that:

- a has 2 or more distinct relationship types,
- a  is connected to at least 10 other people

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. a has 2 or more distinct relationship types
2. a is connected to at least 10 other people

use this query with intermediate aggregation:

```
MATCH (p:Person)-[r:FAMILY|:FRIEND|:COWORKER]->(other:Person)
WITH p, count(distinct type(r)) as c, count(distinct other) as people
WHERE c > 2 and people >= 10
RETURN p
```

(you can also leave off the provided rel-types in the query)

Only for the sizes you can use a path expression, which is faster.

```
MATCH (p:Person)
WHERE SIZE((p)-[:FAMILY|:FRIEND|:COWORKER]->()) >= 10
RETURN p
```

Comment: thanks! Any good recommendations for a tutorial on "advanced" cypher queries?